# Design of Application in Azure Service Fabric

Tags: azure, architecture, asp.net-web-api2, azure-service-fabric

I need help how to think about designing our application to fit into the new Azure Service Fabric template.

Today we have an application built on Azure Cloud Services. The application is built around DDD and we have separate bounded contexts for different subsystem parts of the application. The bounded contexts are today hosted in one worker role that exposes these subsystems using a single WebAPI.

Additionally we have one Web Role hosting the web frontend and one Worker Role processing a background queue.

We strive to move to a micro services architecture. The first thing I planned to do was to extract all bounded context into their own API-hosts. This will result in 5-10 new WebAPI services supporting our subsystems.

To my question, should all of these subsystem/bounded context/API-hosts be their own Service Fabric Application or a service within a single Service Fabric Application?

I've read the documentation, found here [Service Fabric Application Model](https://azure.microsoft.com/sv-se/documentation/articles/service-fabric-application-model/), over and over and I can't figure out where my services fits in.

We want the system to support different versions of the services, and the services should also be possible to scale different from another. There might even be a requirement to have one micro service to run in a larger VM size then the rest.

Please can someone guide me in which suits my needs.

Comment: If you want to upgrade portions independently, they should each be applications. As for how to architect your applications, that is really up to your individual needs. Make sure you set up your partitioning schemes to account for future growth. With SF, you put all your partitions on a small number of machines and then later spread them out as your grow vs. adding more partitions down the road.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you have the right idea, in general terms, that each bounded context is a (micro) service. Service Fabric gives you two levels of organization with applications and services, where an application is a logical grouping of services. Here's what that means for you:

Logically speaking, think of an application as a cohesive set of functionality. The services that collectively form that cohesive set of functionality should be grouped as an application. You can ask yourself, for each service: "does it make sense to deploy this service by itself without these other services?" If the answer is no, then they should probably be grouped in the same application.

Developmentally speaking, the Visual Studio tooling is geared a bit more toward multiple services in one application, but you can have multiple applications in one solution too.

Operationally speaking, an application represents a process boundary, upgrade group, and versioning group:

- Each instance of an application you create gets its own process (or set of processes if you have multiple service types in the application). Service instances of a service type share host processes. Service instances of different service types get their own process per type.
- The application is the top level upgrade unit, that is, every upgrade you do is an application upgrade. You can upgrade individual services within an application (you don't always have to upgrade every service within an application), but each time you do an upgrade, the application version changes.
- You can create side-by-side instances of different versions of the same application type in your cluster. You cannot create side-by-side instances of different versions of the same service type within an application instance.

Placement and scale is done at the service. So for example, you can scale one service in an application, and you can place another service on a larger VM.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer! Helped me a lot :-)

Comment: If we go with seperate applications but each service need to communicate with services in other applications what is the best way (Context: development and testing) ? Kuberenetes provides the Azure Dev Space option with AKS to make this scenario of micro service development with inner loop iteration. Any guidance on service fabric would be very helpful,