# Local cluster does not allow same application type with a different version in local service fabric cluster

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

The following post (on stackoverflow.com):

[Design of Application in Azure Service Fabric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37567644/design-of-application-in-azure-service-fabric)

suggested that it is possible to have side by side installation of same application type with a different version. I tried to install a new version of application (fabric:/ServiceFabApp1 with a new version of 2.0.0 and of ServiceFabApp1Type) on my local cluster (that already has same application name with same application type with version 1.0.3 i.e. fabric:/ServiceFabApp1 with a existing version of 1.0.3 and of ServiceFabApp1Type) and got following error:

*An application with name 'fabric:/ServiceFabApp1' already exists, its Type is 'ServiceFabApp1Type' and Version is 
'1.0.3'.
                    You must first remove the existing application before a new application can be deployed or provide 
a new name for the application.*

Is this by design that application type (for multiple versions) can be same but the application name must be different for each version? Or it simply does not work on the local cluster but works in the azure cloud? Or is my interpretation of the information in the above link is incorrect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Application *types* (eg. ServiceFabricApp1Type) can have one or more versions but an application *instance* (eg. fabric:/ServiceFabricApp1) can only be running one version at a time.

Thus, if you want to have two different versions of your application type running in your local cluster, you will need two different application instances, such that you can have, say, fabric://ServiceFabricApp1 running version 1.0.0 and fabric:/ServiceFabricApp2 running version 2.0.0. The easiest way to do this with the VS tools is to create two application parameters files, each of which defines a distinct app instance name. You can then choose which of the current instances to target with the current version that you're building. To move back and forth between versions of the type in VS, you'll probably want to just create a branch for each.

Comment: You would still need to have 2 deployment packages in that case, wouldn't you?

Comment: Yes, but VS will generate, copy, and register the package for you as part of the Publish. So you work on 1.0.0 branch and publish using parameters file 1, creating fabric:/ServiceFabricApp1. Behind the scenes, this will generate, copy, and register a 1.0.0 package in the cluster's image store. Then you switch to a 2.0.0 branch, make changes, and publish using parameters file 2, creating fabric:/ServiceFabricApp2. Again, this will generate, copy, and register a 2.0.0 package in the cluster. Of course, you can also do the package/copy/register/new steps manually outside of VS if you prefer.

Comment: Thank you for confirmation. A lot of answers are biased towards VS approach. Same amount attention should be given to non-VS approaches.

Comment: Yep, great point. I assumed based on the error he cited and the fact that he was asking specifically about the local cluster that he was probably trying to deploy from VS, which admittedly does not do a great job of surfacing some of these concepts.

Comment: You are correct, I was publishing from VS to my local cluster.

Comment: @SeanMcKenna-MSFT in my case, even with devCluster, I'm doing everything in an automated fashion (via code, but not from VS).

Answer (score 0):

When you deploy a SF application, there are several steps:
 1. Copying application package to the service SF image store
 2. Provision application
 3. Deploy/upgrade application

Step #1 is just copying the package to the SF cluster image store. 
Step #2 provisions a new version of the application so that SF can either deploy that application, or upgrade an existing application if it has already been deployed. 
Step #3 depends on what you've done before. If you have already deployed version X of your app, you can't deploy version X+1. You can only upgrade/downgrade.

If you need to run multiple instances of applications with the same version, you'll need to create different packages where name of the app is a unique name (a multi-tenant scenario).

Comment: In the application type vs application name conversation, the application name is considered an instance? If so, in my thinking, application type is like a class in C# and application name is an instance of that class, that is why I am confused about application instance having a different name for the same application type. Looks my analogy to C# does not work. What is the better way to think about this?

Comment: The OO analogy of types and instances is perfectly appropriate. Your application instances (also referred to as "named applications") have different names in the same way that different instances of the same C# type have different names.

Comment: Aha. I guess I was focusing on the right side of the instance assignment in C# analogy where as you are suggesting to focus on the left side of the assignment (such as different variable name).