# Running different versions in different partitions in a local cluster

Tags: c#, azure-service-fabric

I'm evaluating ServiceFabric and are running named partitions to handle different geographic areas (`north`, `west`, `east`, `south`).

Two of the regions are larger and will process more information. Therefore they are also more sensitive to interruptions.

I therefore want to be able to deploy a new version to only the smaller regions. When we see that those works OK it's fine to deploy the new version to the larger ones.

From what I can [tell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37824818/local-cluster-does-not-allow-same-application-type-with-a-different-version-in-l) it's possible to run multiple versions in the same cluster. But is it possible to run multiple versions in different partitions for the same application type within a local cluster?

Comment: You could do a deployment and pause at each upgrade domain. It won't be a single partition, but it will achieve what you likely want, partial deployment to validate your code. If you write health checks into your service or use a watchdog service during deployment, you can run all of your checks against the upgraded domain and cause it to rollback automatically if you detect an unhealthy condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot upgrade individual partitions. One App instance can only have one version.

Consider changing your setup to run multiple app instances, one for every region.
You can upgrade application instances one by one. Each instance can have its own version.

Read this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-application-upgrade-tutorial-powershell) for more info about how this works. They use PowerShell to upgrade a single app instance, specifying name and version as arguments. (Step 5)