# Single Service Fabric application referencing multiple external Web API's

Tags: azure-service-fabric

My question is *somewhat similar* to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37567644/design-of-application-in-azure-service-fabric), but the answer doesn't really help me, unless i'm missing something.

If i want to deploy 10+ stateless services (OWIN-based Web API's) into a Service Fabric cluster, well from my understanding of ASF, i would:

1. Create a new Service Fabric Application in Visual Studio (call it "MyBackendServices")
2. Create 10+ Stateless Web API's
3. Add them to the Service Fabric Application
4. Deploy to a cluster.

But wouldn't this involve creating all the Web API's in the same Visual Studio solution as the Service Fabric application?

My concern is if we want teams to be fully autonomous, they ideally shouldn't need to share the same Visual Studio solution?

Currently each "team" has their own GitHub repository and Visual Studio solution, and each API gets deployed independently.

I was hoping to port this setup to ASF, where each Web API is it's own solution,  and they somehow get packaged into the one Service Fabric application.

Can anyone help me on this?

Thanks

Comment: Any reason why you can't put each one in its own application? That's what I'm doing anyway. Seems to work quite well.

Comment: @mardoxx can you elaborate pls? How do you decide when to group them together in an application vs not?

Comment: If the situation requires it or not ;) I'm not entirely sure! I suppose if you need a simple deployable multi tenant solution then you'd have everything in one application. Applications' services can be upgraded independently but it's not very friendly to having each service developed independently in its own err soirce repository.

Answer (score 2):

I keep each service in it's own solution (and repo) and bring things together into a single application only at deployment time. Build and deployment occurs via PowerShell which can be triggered as part of a CI/CD process. Only the updated services are modified and I have it updating the manifest versions automatically using the current date/time.

For service that have other service dependencies, I've references their project within the solution so I can easily debug, but only the primary service is deployed.

**Adding more detail to the answer, the comment block is too small.**

I created a directory to place the release versions in the correct SF directory structure. I copy the ApplicationManifest.xml for the release to that directory, though you could make this a repo and check just that file in. I have a buildrelease.ps1 that enumerates the repos and runs msbuild for the release configuration. For that configuration, I'm not building anything but the service to be deployed (no unit tests or other test apps for debugging purposes). The version is generated automatically based on the date and time, e.g. 2017_05_31_1702. This is what is updated in the service manifest and eventually in the application manifest. After a successful build, the service manifest is updated back in solution directory like this:

```
    $serviceManifestPath = "$solutionDir\src\${ServiceName}Service\PackageRoot\ServiceManifest.xml"
Set-ItemProperty $serviceManifestPath -name IsReadOnly -value $false

$serviceManifestXml = [xml](Get-Content $serviceManifestPath)
$ns = New-Object System.Xml.XmlNamespaceManager($serviceManifestXml.NameTable)
$ns.AddNamespace("ns", $serviceManifestXml.DocumentElement.NamespaceURI)

$serviceManifestXml.ServiceManifest.Version = $NewVersion
$serviceManifestXml.ServiceManifest.CodePackage.Version = $NewVersion
$serviceManifestXml.ServiceManifest.ConfigPackage.Version = $NewVersion
$serviceManifestXml.Save($serviceManifestPath)
```

Next msbuild is called again to package the SFProj.

```
$buildResult = & $msBuild $sfproj /p:Configuration=Release /nologo /v:M /fl /flp:LogFile="msbuild.log;Verbosity=Normal" /nr:false /target:package
```

Today I'm only building services that have a modified service manifest, so you have to remember to modify the manifest when you modify code/config. I'd like to improve that, just not enough time.

After packaging, the solution's release{service name}Service.pkg is copied to the release folder. When the script is done, the resulting directory contains any changed services in the correct format.

Next script is a deployment script per cluster. I'm sure one could be created that is data driven. This connects to the remote cluster, tests the package, uploads the package to the image store and does a new or upgrade depending on if the application already exists. I have a version of this that can deploy to my one-box so I can test/debug all of the services running together all using local configuration.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for. Any chance you could share some code snippets or documentation on how you achieved this? Do you have a repository/sln with just the service fabric application manifest? Then your CI clones _all_ the various repositories to a folder then runs the deploy script as if they were always in the one place etc?

Comment: indeed i'd love to see your response to this, todd

Comment: Yes, I have a single application contained within a single directory structure with a single ApplicationManifest. Then my CI scripts compare the ServiceManifest of the source with the current version in the corresponding release directory, if anything has changed, I update the versions of everything in both manifests and copy the code, config and data. I use a generate date format for versions e.g. 2017-11-13-1700. This is what is put into the manifests.